# Mod Rewrite question

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost

Is there a way to rewrite

```
http://localhost/embed/player.swf?file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yKDhm4_-90
```

to something smaller?

or is there a way to change this into

```
http://localhost/embed/script.php?id=7yKDhm4_-90
```

What can i do?

**UPDATE**

i've tried with something like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Connection: close');
$video_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$content = readfile("http://localhost/embed/player.swf?file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$video_id");
echo $content;
```

but it is mot working.

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the following in the .htaccess file (create it if it doesn't already exist) in your website's root directory:

```
RewriteRule ^embed/player.swf?file=([0-9a-zA-Z0-9]+) embed/player.swf?file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Note that this _internally rewrites_ the "short" URL back to the "long" URL. The "long" URL still needs to be changed to the "short" URL in the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible with either method; I'll post a possible PHP solution.

```
include("player.swf?file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={$_GET['id']}");
```

This is a very simplified solution, so you would still have to handle filtering your input, escaping output, and empty IDs if you wanted to use it in a production environment.

Comment: is there anybody knowing how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score -2):

Try the simple and easy solution no need to specify headers

```
<?php if ($_REQUEST['id']): ?> // youtube video id

<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_REQUEST['id']; ?>" frameborder="0">
</iframe>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Very strange, to come up with an IFRAME, if someone asks for a mod_rewrite solution.